# mongodb architecture

Tags: mongodb

I understand MongoDB can be setup as an un-sharded replica set or sharded.  Sharded is used by scalability of very large datasets.

Question is, at what point do I know that I should use Sharded versus basic replica sets of 3 mongodb nodes?

Answer (score 1):

As always, it depends. When your database is too big to hold entirely in RAM in a single machine, think about sharding. As always, the best way to know for sure is to test in your specific situation/architecture/usage patterns, and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the data set size a few more parameters that can be taken into account.

1. Write load. Replica set will allow read scaling (1 master - many slaves), but if the app is write heavy then sharding is one way of distributing the write load. But for this to be effective the way the data gets distributed across the cluster should match the concurrent write pattern.
2. Multi data center deployment.  If the app needs to be geographically distributed tag aware sharding (introduced in 2.2) allows you to keep

Answer (score 0):

As @gkamal mentioned you need to consider sharding when your data store start hitting 60-70% of the single box size and load predominantly write heavy.

The main difference between unshaded 3 replica sets and sharded instances that replica sets won't scale write load. As a primary server will be a bottleneck for the writes primary because of locking overhead. On the other hand, if sharding done correctly, it'll aliviate the load of writes/reads as each shard splits across multiple isolated instances.